# find-name-dired followed by deletion of root owned files

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'm using `find-name-dired` to find a bunch of files (all with .orig file ending)

I would then like to mark all the files in the resulting *Find* buffer for deletion then delete them

Unfortunately they are root owned, so the delete fails due to lack of permissions

Is there some workaround here, tramp or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using sudo through tramp.  When `find-name-dired` prompts for the directory name, modify it and put `/sudo::` at the start.  E.g. change `/foo/bar` into `/sudo::/foo/bar`. (Take care of relative paths and `~` paths.)  It will prompt for your sudo password, and then you should be able to delete files as usual.

Answer (score 2):

You can presumably mark the files, then use <kbd>!</kbd> `sudo rm`